# Integer arithmetic when overflow exists

Tags: c++, c, integer-arithmetic

Two 32 bit integer values A and B, are processed to give the 32 bit integers C and D as per the following rules. Which of the rule(s) is(are) reversible?
i.e.  is it possible to obtain A and B given c and D in all condition?

A.   C = (int32)(A+B), D = (int32)(A-B)

B.   C = (int32)(A+B),  D= (int32)((A-B)>>1)

C.   C = (int32)(A+B),  D = B

D.   C = (int32)(A+B), D = (int32)(A+2*B)

E.   C = (int32)(A*B),  D = (int32)(A/B)

A few questions about the integer arithmetic. Modular addition forms amathematical structure known as an *abelian group*. **How about signed addition?** It's also commutative (that’s where the “abelian” part comes in) and associative, **is this forms a n an *abelian group***?

Given that integer addition is commutative and associative, C is apparently true, because we can retrieve A by (A+(B-B)). **What about D?** Can we assume that `2 * B = B + B` st. `B = A+B+B-(A+B)`?

And multiplication is more complicated, but I know that it can not be retrieve A if there is an overflow.

Comment: Only `unsigned` integer types form groups with respect to addition in C and C++. Signed addition usually can't, already for the simple reason that `INT_MIN` usually has no inverse in the common 2complement representation.

Comment: @JensGustedt What about the specific problem above?

Comment: Take `INT32_MIN` for `A` and `B` and it is implementation defined what will happen in any case, so there is no answer. I get the suspicion that you are trying to get a consistent answer to an ill-posed exercise. Often we see such exercise here that come from not-so-well-informed teachers that take two's complement for granted and never heard of signals that can be raised in case of overflow. Don't do such stuff with `int32` (BTW the standard `typedef` is called `int32_t`) but with `uint32_t`. Where do you have these questions from?

Comment: @JensGustedt *Microsoft intern hiring written test*. But I've seen it somewhere else.

Comment: @JensGustedt I don't quit get you. This question is asking you that which one can retrieve A and B even under overflow. I think C is right anyway. Because addition for integers is commutative and associative. So I can retrieve A by `E = C - D = A + B - B = A` and B by `C - E`. What do you think? And I take D as a right answer, see my questions.

Comment: No, this "test" has no solution as everybody is trying to tell. If there is overflow the result is implementation defined at best. It just makes no sense to ask such sort of question. It this is really something MS test for its interns, this would again prove that they don't have much of a clue about C. Maybe if you'd change the question in what would be possible with a MS compiler, that is a very specific compiler, there might be an answer.

Answer (score 8):

This is a quote from 5 [expr] paragraph 4:

> If during the evaluation of an expression, the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type, the behavior is undefined.

What makes overflow for unsigned integers work is defined in 3.9.1 [basic.fundamental] paragraph 4:

> Unsigned integers shall obey the laws of arithmetic modulo 2<sup>n</sup> where n is the number of bits in the value representation of that particular size of integer.

Basically this says that you shall not overflow when using signed integer arithmetic. If you do, all bets are off. This implies that signed integers do not form an Abelian group in C++.

Comment: But signed addition is commutative and associative. This is not sufficient for it to form an abelian group? And any suggestions for the specific problem above(the 2nd question)?

Comment: @zoujyjs: The rules would need to apply to any value in the group. However, they clearly do not apply, e.g., for `A == std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` and `B == 2` because `A + B` and `A * B` both overflow, resulting in undefined behavior.